# How to identify button class element?

Tags: python, selenium, element

I tried the following to identify elements but I am getting "No element found" message when I run my scripts.

Method1 tried:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Adopt and Initial']").click()
```

Method2 tried:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn-primary.btn.left.item-alt").click()
```

HTML of the button:

Updated Html code for the element. This is for docusign.

```
    <div class="dialog is-signature-mode" tabindex="0">
  <header class="dialog-header">
    <h1 class="dialog-title">
      <span class="item-alt" data-group="tagType" data-group-item="signature">Adopt Your Signature</span>
      <span class="item-alt" data-group="tagType" data-group-item="initials" data-selected="">Adopt Your Initials</span>
    </h1>
    <nav class="icons">
      <a class="close" data-action="cancelAdoptSignature">
        <i class="icon-close"></i>
      </a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section class="dialog-body">
    <article id="adopt">

        <header class="ds-title p">
          Confirm your name, initials, and signature.
        </header>
        <div class="full-name">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <label for="full-name">Full Name</label> <span class="error hidden">Name required</span>
            <br>
            <div class="text-input-wrapper">
              <input id="full-name" disabled="" value="QAAuto 01Dec2014_10.41.03" name="fullname" type="text" class="required text-input" maxlength="50">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="initials">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <label for="initials">Initials</label> <span class="error hidden">Initials required</span>
            <br>
            <div class="text-input-wrapper">
              <input id="initials" disabled="" value="Q0" name="initials" type="text" class="required text-input" maxlength="50">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


      <div class="clear-float"></div>
    </article>
    <header class="tab-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#select-style" class="tab tab-select-style selected">Select Style</a></li>
        <li><a href="#draw" class="tab tab-draw">Draw</a></li>


      </ul>
    </header>

      <article id="select-style" class="tab-panel panel-select-style selected">
        <h4 class="normal">Preview <span class="error"></span></h4>
        <div class="signature-preview">
          <div class="signature"><img alt="" src="https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/image.aspx?ti=56b2faad38e7427a99defd1dfaa258ce&amp;insession=1&amp;i=asig150&amp;force=154&amp;s=QAAuto+01Dec2014_10.41.03&amp;f=7_DocuSign&amp;nochrome=0" height="75px" class="signature-img left">
<img alt="" src="https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/image.aspx?ti=56b2faad38e7427a99defd1dfaa258ce&amp;insession=1&amp;i=ainit150&amp;force=155&amp;s=Q0&amp;n=QAAuto+01Dec2014_10.41.03&amp;f=7_DocuSign&amp;nochrome=0" height="75px" class="initials-img right">
<div class="clear-float"></div></div>
          <a class="change-style">
            Change Style
          </a>
          <div class="clear-float"></div>
        </div>
      </article>


      <article id="draw" class="tab-panel panel-draw">
        <h4 class="normal">
          <span class="item-alt-inline" data-group="tagType" data-group-item="signature">Draw your signature</span>
          <span class="item-alt-inline" data-group="tagType" data-group-item="initials" data-selected="">Draw your initials</span>
          <span class="error"></span>
        </h4>
        <a class="clear" data-ds="clear">Clear</a>
        <div class="signature-draw signature">

        <div class="canvas-wrapper"><canvas class="canvas" width="0" height="0"></canvas><canvas class="canvas" width="0" height="0"></canvas></div></div>
      </article>



    <p class="legalese">By clicking Adopt and Sign, I agree that the signature and initials will be the electronic representation of my signature and initials for all purposes when I (or my agent) use them on documents, including legally binding contracts - just the same as a pen-and-paper signature or initial.</p>
    <hr>
    <button class="btn-primary btn left item-alt" data-group="tagType" data-group-item="signature" type="button" data-ds="submit" value="initials">Adopt and Sign</button>
    <button class="btn-primary btn left item-alt" data-group="tagType" data-group-item="initials" type="button" data-ds="submit" value="initials" data-selected="">Adopt and Initial</button>
    <button class="close left btn btn-default" type="button" data-action="cancelAdoptSignature">Cancel</button>
    <div class="clear-float"></div>
  <div class="styles"></div></section>
</div>
```

Comment: I added these for some reason it is not showing up on my post.<button class="btn-primary btn left item-alt" data-group="tagType" data-group-item="initials" type="button" data-ds="submit" value="initials" data-selected="">Adopt and Initial</button>

Comment: I don't know what's in that microscopically-scaled image, but it's not very useful. Paste text into the question.

Comment: Please clarify "not working".

Comment: Updated the question... Let me know if that is still unclear. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you're seeing `NoSuchElement` exceptions, that is usually due to the element either being inside of an `iframe`, or the element loading after Selenium believes the page has finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below xpath and let me know what happens

```
assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("Adopt and Initial"));
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[conatins(text(),'Adopt and Initial')]".click();
```

Now Make sure you use assertion before the command because if the assertion fails then the element is not present in the current frame. so we will have to switch the correct frame before we perform the action. 
Let me know if you try this.

Comment: getpagesource is a java library looks like. I am using Selenium for Python bindings...I tried this instead but it didn't find the element either self.assertTrue(driver.get_window_size("current")
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Adopt and Initial')]").click();

Comment: Can you provide me the HTML code for this element? Are you Sure that element is in the same frame?

Comment: Rupesh- I updated the html in the original post. This element is not in an iframe. But the initial page where you accept the t&c and click the check box is in an iframe. Then, it clicks on one of the check box(outside of iframe) this element appears. Which is what we have difficulty in identifying.